# $stdin.gets is not working when execute ruby script via pipeline

Tags: ruby, command-line

Here comes a sample ruby code:

```
r = gets
puts r
```

if the script is executed standalone from console, it work fine. But if i ran it via pipeline:

```
echo 'testtest' | ruby test.rb
```

`gets` seem is redirected to pipeline inputs, but i need some user input.

How?

Comment: Tested it under MacOS

Comment: `gets` is not being re-directed by Ruby, but at an outer level by the shell/OS. It is still `STDIN` as far as your Ruby script is concerned. You *may* still be able to use code that scans the keyboard directly (I don't know enough to help there), but that would be an unusual situation for a utility intended to run with piped input. Are working in a pipeline and interacting via the keyboard both strict requirements on your code?

Comment: yes. i wrote a program to proceed output of 'svn status' and prompt if user want to resolve conflict. It could not simply be yes or not, user may manually merge changed and mark it as resolved, or just left it unchange.

Comment: I trying to `gets` with forked process, but still not working..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stdin has been attached to the receiving end of the pipe by the invoking shell.  If you really need interactive input you have a couple choices.  You can open the tty input directly, leavng stdin bound to the pipe:

```
tty_input = open('/dev/tty') {|f| f.gets }
```

`/dev/tty` works under linux and OS/x, but might not work everywhere.

Alternatively, you can use a different form of redirection, [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html), under bash to supply the (formerly piped) input as a psuedo-file passed as an argument and leave stdin bound to your terminal:

```
ruby test.rb <(echo 'testtest')

# test.rb
input = open(ARGV[0])
std_input = gets
input.readlines { |line| process_line(line) }
```

Comment: process substitution works. And open('/dev/tty') not working on MacOS ML

Comment: the first code block has a mistake, it should be:
`tty_input = open('/dev/tty') {|f| f.gets }`
(no `do` keyword)