# Ruby, STDIN, and Curses

Tags: ruby, curses

I'm trying to take input from `STDIN` in the same script I'm using `curses`.  It causes ruby to exit immediately and never draw anything with curses on the page.

The following works fine:

```
require 'curses'

Curses.init_screen

begin
  Curses.setpos(6, 3)  # column 6, row 3
  Curses.addstr("Hello")
  Curses.getch  # Wait until user presses some key.
ensure
  Curses.close_screen
end
```

But if I run it with, for example `ls | example.rb`, it fails immediately, even if I consume STDIN with `STDIN.read`.

I have tried stripping `STDIN.read`, and tried solutions from [How to test filter-like Ruby scripts with Pry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623290/how-to-test-filter-like-ruby-scripts-with-pry) with no luck.

Comment: Have you tried `$stdin`?

Comment: Yes, I can  `p $stdin.read`, and get the input.  The issue is whether `$stdin.tty?` is `true` or `false`.  If I run `ls | ruby script.rb`, `$stdin.tty?` is `false`, and `Curses` fails to render anything.  If I run `ruby script.rb`, it will run fine.  `$stdin.read` will wait for me to `ctrl-d` and then work normally, because `$stdin.tty?` is true.  Hope that clarifies the issue a bit.

Comment: It kind of does, so I have a question, are you actually checking if the `stdin` returns true, or are you just attempting to run it through the prompt instead of making an `if/else` to check `true/false`?

Comment: So, if I add the following lines before the `Curses.init_screen`:

    `p $stdin.tty?`
    `p $stdin.read`

If I run my script like `echo "hi" | ruby script.rb`, it produces:

    `false`
    `"hi\n"`

If I run it with just `ruby script.rb`, it waits for input from stdin with a terminating `Ctrl-d`, then produces `true` `"hi\n"`

Comment: [See this gist](https://gist.github.com/r-butler/a8694e3b06cce76c244eb687fee9df9d)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$stdin.gets is not working when execute ruby script via pipeline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613684/stdin-gets-is-not-working-when-execute-ruby-script-via-pipeline)